# VS 2015 Team Services Pull action breaks references. Is there a way around this?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

When my team runs a fetch and pull from Visual Studio 2015 Team Services, the dll references break. The path becomes blank. This is because we use cloud storage to share our references, so the path is different for each local copy. Is there a way to map reference paths?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to achieve this as I know. I would recommend you to use [Package Management](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/what-is-packaging) feature in Visual Studio Team Service to store your dll references and use Nuget to manage the reference in project.